# How does the abstract base class avoid the partial assignment?

Tags: c++

As is talked about in Item 33 in "More Effective C++", the assignment problem is

```
//Animal is a concrete class
Lizard:public Animal{};
Chicken:public Animal{};

Animal* pa=new Lizard('a');
Animal* pb=new Lizard('b');
*pa=*pb;//partial assignment
```

However, if I define `Animal` as an abstract base class, we can also compile and run the sentence:`*pa=*pb`. Partial assignment problem is still there.
See my example:

```
#include <iostream> 
class Ab{ private: int a;
        double b;
    public:
        virtual ~Ab()=0;
};
Ab::~Ab(){}

class C:public Ab{
    private:
        int a;
        double b;
};

class D:public Ab{
    private:
        int a;
        double b;
};

int main()
{
    Ab *pc=new C();
    Ab *pd=new D();
    *pc=*pd;
    return 0;
}
```

Do I miss something? Then what's the real meaning of the abstract base class?

**I got the answer by myself. I missed a code snippet in the book.**
Use protected `operator=` in the base class to avoid `*pa=*pb`. Use abstract base class to avoid `animal1=animal2`.Then the only allowed expressions are `lizard1=lizard2;chicken1=chicken2;`
See the code below:

```
#include <iostream> 
class Ab{ 
    private: 
        int a;
        double b;
    public:
        virtual ~Ab()=0;
    protected:   //!!!!This is the point
        Ab& operator=(const Ab&){...}
};
Ab::~Ab(){}

class C:public Ab{
    public: 
        C& operator=(const C&){...}
    private:
        int a;
        double b;
};

class D:public Ab{
    public:
        D& operator=(const D&){...}
    private:
        int a;
        double b;
};

int main()
{
    Ab *pc=new C();
    Ab *pd=new D();
    *pc=*pd;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So animal is concrete or abstract? and you wrote 'pa' twice (there is no 'pb' in your code).

Comment: @flyman Sorry, I just corrected my mistakes and made it clear to understand.

Comment: Try it with a pure virtual function that is not a destructor.

Comment: Just FYI, a common term for this "partial assignment" is "slicing."

Comment: Why do you think an abstract class should make a difference to slicing?

Answer (score 2):

The abstract base class cannot help in case of assignment because the base sub-object is not instantiated (what an abstract class would block) but is sliced off the derived object (i.e. the assignment is done between already existing base sub-objects).

To avoid the problem the only solution I can think to is

1. make the assignment virtual
2. check in the assignment that the source instance is of the correct type

In code

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int bx;
    Base(int bx) : bx(bx) {}

    virtual Base& operator=(const Base& other) {
        bx = other.bx;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct A : Base {
    int x;
    A(int bx, int x) : Base(bx), x(x) {}
    A& operator=(const Base& other) {
        const A& other_a = dynamic_cast<const A&>(other);
        Base::operator=(other);
        x = other_a.x;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct B : Base {
    int x;
    B(int bx, int x) : Base(bx), x(x) {}
    B& operator=(const Base& other) {
        const B& other_b = dynamic_cast<const B&>(other);
        Base::operator=(other);
        x = other_b.x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The `dynamic_cast<const A&>(other)` is the operation that will fail if the object passed to the assignment operator is not of the correct derived type (it can be a sub-derived object, but this should be logically ok for an assignment **source**).

As an example:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    Base *pa1 = new A(1, 2);
    Base *pa2 = new A(3, 4);
    Base *pb1 = new B(5, 6);
    Base *pb2 = new B(7, 8);

    *pa1 = *pa2; std::cout << pa1->bx << "/" << dynamic_cast<A*>(pa1)->x << "\n";
    *pb1 = *pb2; std::cout << pb1->bx << "/" << dynamic_cast<B*>(pb1)->x << "\n";
    std::cout << "Ok so far\n";

    *pa1 = *pb1; // Runtime error here (bad cast)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the base sub-object is not instantiated (what an abstract class would block) but is sliced off the derived object (i.e. the assignment is done between already existing base sub-objects)." Good point.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that your base class has pure virtual functions because you haven't defined the `operator=` for any of the classes. So when the compiler sees this statement:

```
*pc=*pd;
```

where pc and pd are both of type `Ab`, it will call the default assignment operator for `Ab`, which will result in partial assignment. As in the following example, I get the output as `"Abstract Base"` which is from abstract base class:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() =0;
    virtual A& operator=(const A& rhs) {
        std::cout << "Abstract Base";
            return *this;
    }
};


class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout << "b:foo";
    }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        std::cout << "c:foo";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* b = new B();
    A* c = new C();

    *b = *c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you explicitly define operator= in every class in this derivation hierarchy, the abstract base class is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not handled the assignment operators in your classes, you land up in situation partial assignment as Scot clearly describes in his article.

You need to handle assignments in your classes. In current design default implicit assignment operator of Ab is called and thus all the properties of children class are lost.

To avoid this you should have an implementation like this:

```
   class Ab{ private: int a;
        double b;
    public:
        virtual ~Ab()=0;
        virtual Ab& operator=(const Ab& rhs){cout<<"in Ab="<<endl;} 
};
Ab::~Ab(){}

class C:public Ab{

    C& operator=(const Ab& rhs){cout<<"in C="<<endl;
      return operator=(dynamic_cast<const C&>(rhs)); }

    C& operator=(const C& rhs){
       cout<<"do somethin in C="<<endl;
   }
    private:
        int a;
        double b;
};

class D:public Ab{

D& operator=(const Ab& rhs){cout<<"in D="<<endl;
      return operator=(dynamic_cast<const D&>(rhs)); }

    D& operator=(const D& rhs){
       cout<<"do somethin in D="<<endl;
   }
    private:
        int a;
        double b;
};
```

Comment: If you explicitly define operator= in every class in this derivation hierarchy, the abstract base class is not needed.

Comment: @particle128 operator= in every class is there to handle a case where when child classes object are equated and we want to avoid equation of different child classes. Also having operator= in every child class you make it possible for complete assignment. And one should aim for a abstract base class which just defines a concept and child classes specialization.